# Why determinant map matrices is a polynomial and not identically zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in M_n(C)$ are invertible then we consider the map $c \rightarrow det(A+cB)$ which is a *polynomial*. How to prove that the polynomial $det(A+cB)$ not identically zero? thanks in advanced.

Comment: I can't understand what this is meant to say. You have two given matrices $P$ and $Q$, and you consider that map? What are you trying to prove about this map?

Comment: The sentence describing what you are trying to prove makes no sense at all.

Comment: I believe that the OP is asking why the polynomial $\det(A+cB)$ is not identically zero. But this is obvious since for $c=0$ it gives $\det(A)$ which is non-zero by hypothesis.

Comment: @AndreaMori yes u right, but how to prove it formally?

Comment: I think that what I said is already pretty formal! A polynomial with a non-zero constant term is not identically zero :)

Comment: If you cannot show the formulation in my answer with your definition, you may need to prove $f(x)=\det(A+xB)$ by *induction*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not seem clear depend on your definition of determinants.

It's a theorem that "there exists a unique $n$-linear alternating map $D$ on $M_n(R)$ with the property $D(I_n)=1$". ($R$ denotes any commutative ring with unity)

So, no matter what your definition is, you can show that $\det (A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n A_{i,\sigma_i}$ for any $A\in M_n(R)$.

Note that polynomial ring is a conmutative ring with unity. So from the above formulation, it's *very clear* that $\det(A+XB)$ is a polynomial.

Now, let's denote $f(X)=\det(A+XB)$. And above formulation directly shows that $f(x)=\det(A+xB)$ for every element $x\in F$. (One should prove this fact!)( $F$ denotes a field)

Since $f(0)=\det(A)\neq 0$, $f(X)$ is not a zero polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P(c)=\det(A+cB)$, which is clearly a polynomial in $c$, since the determinant is a form of degree $n$ in the matrix entries.

Note that 
$$
P(0)=\det(A)\neq0
$$
since $A$ is invertible by hypothesis. But then $P(c)$ is a polynomial with non-zero constant term, so cannot be identically zero.